# Blazor Modal Form Validation: You've to click the cancel button twice to close the modal when you delete a form field

Tags: c#, blazor

In Blazor I'm using modal dialogs for CRUD. When I open a modal to edit a record and I delete (for example) the user name and then directly click the Cancel button, form validation still kicks in. The modal does not close.

[image: Blazor Cancel Validation]
I need to click the Cancel button again to close the modal.

I know I can put the cancel button outside the `EditForm`, but then you'll see a validation message flashing before the dialog closes. And I want my cancel button next to my submit button in the modal footer.

Is there any way to override the form validation when I press the Cancel button? And I'd rather not want to use JavaScript Interop, just plain Blazor.

*Working Code Example:*

```
@page "/cancel"
@using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

<h3>Cancel Validation</h3>

<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="Login">Login</button>
<hr />
<p>Status: @status</p>

@if (showModal)
{
    <div class="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" style="display:block" id="taskModal">
        <div class="modal-dialog shadow-lg bg-white rounded" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title">Login</h5>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <EditForm Model="user" OnValidSubmit="HandleValidSubmit">
                        <DataAnnotationsValidator />
                        <ValidationSummary />
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label class="col-3 col-form-label">Email: </label>
                            <InputText class="col-8 form-control" @bind-Value="user.Email" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label class="col-3 col-form-label">Password: </label>
                            <InputText type="password" class="col-8 form-control" @bind-Value="user.Password" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" @onclick="CancelSubmit">Cancel</button>
                        </div>
                    </EditForm>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

@code {

    public class UserLogin
    {
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Email is required")]
        public string Email { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Password is required")]
        public string Password { get; set; }
    }

    UserLogin user = new UserLogin();

    bool showModal;
    string status;

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        showModal = false;
        status = "Init";
        // for demo purposes, if you delete user.Email in the login dialog, you'll need to press 'Cancel' 2 times.
        user.Email = "user@example.com";
        user.Password = "12345";
    }

    private void Login()
    {
        status = "Show Login Modal";
        showModal = true;
    }

    private void HandleValidSubmit()
    {
        status = "Valid Submit";
        showModal = false;
    }

    private void CancelSubmit()
    {
        status = "Cancelled"; 
        showModal = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: What means _override the form validation when I press the Cancel button_ ? Are you talking about clear validation errors? For it I use a custom context on editform ( Instead of `EditForm Model="user"` I use `EditForm EditContext="ctx"` where ctx is `new EditContext(user);` and I create a new context on cancel ) More info at [ASP.NET Core Blazor forms and validation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/forms-validation?view=aspnetcore-3.1)

Comment: @daniherrera I mean that when I click the cancel button I don't want any kind of form validation. I just want the modal to disappear. But if the form fields are populated, and when I then delete the contents of a form filed (like email) and then directly click the cancel button, validation still is activated, the modal doesn't close. It shows the validation message (see screenshot above). Then I have to click the cancel button again to close the modal.

Comment: I posted an answer to my own question but I've made a mistake. Didn't see it at first but @enet posted a message which made that clear. So I deleted my own answer. I need to look into this further.

Comment: @Jaap, when you clear the email text box and press the cancel button validation takes place before the event handler for the cancel button is triggered. This is because validation occurs when the email text box lose focus, and you can't press the cancel button without first causing the text box to lose focus. I'm of the opinion that it is not a bug, but rather a limitation which you can overcome by using custom validation.

Comment: @enet Yep, it's no Blazor bug. What you say make sense. If I use TAB after deleting the contents of the field clicking Cancel works directly. But I want to use Cancel directly and no validation whatsoever when I click Cancel. I need to spend more time on this. I'm looking into fluent validation also, maybe that solves my problem but I don't know. Yet :) Gotta love coding!

Comment: Yes, I also thought of "fluent validation", but I have other ideas in my mind which i'll try later on...

Comment: The funny thing though, is that the input box changes to red when you delete the contents and press submit. So some validation is actually happening, but no validation text is displayed.  With `<ValidationSummary Model="user" />` that is.

Comment: @Jaap, I have bad news... I tried using fluent validation instead, but the problem persists. I'll try to investigate and let you know about it...

Comment: @enet I've found something, I'll post the code in the answer. It is not an ideal solution, I'll explain more below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Today I found a much more simpler solution... just use a <div> instead of <button>  :)

So just change your cancel button to:

```
   <div type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" @onclick="CancelSubmit">Cancel</div>
```

The validation will not be triggered this way, but your serverside code will still be executed normally.

Comment: On a similar note; you can keep it as a `<button>` as long as the `type=button` :
<button class="btn btn-lg btn-secondary" @onclick="CancelSubmit" type="button">Cancel</button>

Answer (score 4):

@Jaap, here's a solution that is based on the internals of Forms validation. I hope it'll satisfy you until a better solution is offered.

Forms validation support in Blazor, added to the EditContext object is performed on two level: object-level and field-level. When you click on the Submit button, the whole Model is validated. We've already seen that the Submit button works perfectly well, and does not allow you to submit unless the Model's fields' values are valid. When you hit the Cancel button and the Model's fields' values are valid, the dialog is closed without issue. But when one or more fields are having invalid values (as for instance, after clearing the email field), and you click on the Cancel button, a field-level validation instantly starts, before the code in the Cancel button's event handler has the slightest chance to do something. This behavior is by design and is repeated even when I used Fluent Validation instead of DataAnnotations validation. Conclusion: It is our limitations, not the system. We need to invest more time in learning Blazor.
The solution I propose is to disable a field-level validation when we click on the Cancel button, and thus instantly close the dialog **without** any validation taking place at all.

Note: My code is using Fluent Validation as I was experimenting with Fluent Validation, but the same can be done with DataAnnotations Validation as well. The code in both cases is almost identical, and has really nothing to do with Fluent Validation. Note that I have adapted the Fluent Validation sample code by [Chris Sainty](https://chrissainty.com/using-fluentvalidation-for-forms-validation-in-razor-components/)

### UserLogin.cs

```
public class UserLogin
{
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

### UserLoginValidator.cs

```
public class UserLoginValidator : AbstractValidator<UserLogin>
    {
       public UserLoginValidator()
     {

         RuleFor(user => user.Email).NotEmpty().WithMessage("You must enter an email address");
         RuleFor(user => user.Email).EmailAddress().WithMessage("You must provide a valid email address");
         RuleFor(user => user.Password).NotEmpty().WithMessage("You must enter a password");
         RuleFor(user => user.Password).MaximumLength(50).WithMessage("Password cannot be longer than 50 characters");
    }
 }
```

### FluentValidationValidator.cs

```
public class FluentValidationValidator : ComponentBase
{
    [CascadingParameter] EditContext CurrentEditContext { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public bool ShouldValidate { get; set; }

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        if (CurrentEditContext == null)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException($"{nameof(FluentValidationValidator)} requires a cascading " +
                $"parameter of type {nameof(EditContext)}. For example, you can use {nameof(FluentValidationValidator)} " +
                $"inside an {nameof(EditForm)}.");
        }

        CurrentEditContext.AddFluentValidation(ShouldValidate);
    }
}
```

### EditContextFluentValidationExtensions.cs

```
 public static class EditContextFluentValidationExtensions
{
    public static EditContext AddFluentValidation(this EditContext editContext, bool shouldValidate)
    {
        if (editContext == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(editContext));
        }

        var messages = new ValidationMessageStore(editContext);

        editContext.OnValidationRequested +=
            (sender, eventArgs) => ValidateModel((EditContext)sender, messages);

        editContext.OnFieldChanged +=
            (sender, eventArgs) => ValidateField(editContext, messages, eventArgs.FieldIdentifier, shouldValidate);

        return editContext;
    }

    private static void ValidateModel(EditContext editContext, ValidationMessageStore messages)
    {
        var validator = GetValidatorForModel(editContext.Model);
        var validationResults = validator.Validate(editContext.Model);

        messages.Clear();
        foreach (var validationResult in validationResults.Errors)
        {
            messages.Add(editContext.Field(validationResult.PropertyName), validationResult.ErrorMessage);
        }

        editContext.NotifyValidationStateChanged();
    }

    private static void ValidateField(EditContext editContext, ValidationMessageStore messages, in FieldIdentifier fieldIdentifier, bool shouldValidate)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(fieldIdentifier.FieldName.ToString());

        if (shouldValidate)
        {
            var properties = new[] { fieldIdentifier.FieldName };
            var context = new FluentValidation.ValidationContext(fieldIdentifier.Model, new PropertyChain(), new MemberNameValidatorSelector(properties));

            var validator = GetValidatorForModel(fieldIdentifier.Model);
            var validationResults = validator.Validate(context);

            messages.Clear(fieldIdentifier);

            foreach (var validationResult in validationResults.Errors)
            {
                messages.Add(editContext.Field(validationResult.PropertyName), validationResult.ErrorMessage);
            }

            editContext.NotifyValidationStateChanged();
        }
    }

    private static IValidator GetValidatorForModel(object model)
    {
        var abstractValidatorType = typeof(AbstractValidator<>).MakeGenericType(model.GetType());
        var modelValidatorType = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes().FirstOrDefault(t => t.IsSubclassOf(abstractValidatorType));
        var modelValidatorInstance = (IValidator)Activator.CreateInstance(modelValidatorType);

        return modelValidatorInstance;
    }
}
```

### Cancel.razor

```
@page "/cancel"
@using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

<h3>Cancel Validation</h3>

<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="Login">Login</button>
<hr />
<p>Status: @status</p>

@if (showModal)
{
    <div class="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" style="display:block" id="taskModal">
        <div class="modal-dialog shadow-lg bg-white rounded" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title">Login</h5>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <EditForm Model="user" OnValidSubmit="HandleValidSubmit">
                        @*<DataAnnotationsValidator />*@
                        <FluentValidationValidator ShouldValidate="false" />
                        @*<ValidationSummary />*@
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label class="col-3 col-form-label">Email: </label>
                            <InputText class="col-8 form-control" @bind-Value="user.Email" />
                            <ValidationMessage For="@(() => user.Email)" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label class="col-3 col-form-label">Password: </label>
                            <InputText type="password" class="col-8 form-control" @bind-Value="user.Password" />
                            <ValidationMessage For="@(() => user.Password)" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" @onclick="CancelSubmit">Cancel</button>
                        </div>
                    </EditForm>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

@code {
    UserLogin user = new UserLogin();

    bool showModal;
    string status;

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        showModal = false;
        status = "Init";
        // for demo purposes, if you delete user.Email in the login dialog, you'll need to press 'Cancel' 2 times.
        user.Email = "user@example.com";
        user.Password = "12345";
    }

    private void Login()
    {
        status = "Show Login Modal";

        showModal = true;
    }

    private void HandleValidSubmit()
    {
        status = "Valid Submit";
        showModal = false;
    }

    private void CancelSubmit()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("CancelSubmit");

        status = "Cancelled";
        showModal = false;
    }
}
```

Note that the FluentValidationValidator component has a property named  ShouldValidate which we set to false in order to remove field-level validation. Please, follow the flow of execution it's very simple. I almost do nothing to solve the issue, which make me think that perhaps there's a shorter and better way to do it. 
You may need to install Fluent Validation package...
Good luck...

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer and example code. And thank you for your time you've invested in this. It is certainly an improvement and I agree with everything you say.

Comment: @enet I noticed that in FluidValidator v9.3.0, the following line is causing error in the `ValidateModel` extension method: `var validationResults = validator.Validate(editContext.Model);`. Any idea on how to resolve that?

Comment: @enet, the line `CurrentEditContext.AddFluentValidation(ShouldValidate);` is also an error in `FluentValidationValidator -> OnInitialized()`

Comment: @Hassan Gulzar, yes, you're right. I've updated my code sample to use v9.3.0. , and get the same errors. This requires a major change in the code whose author is not me. Here's a link to the same author, and code sample on whom my answer here dependent. Yes, his code also contains major changes and take into account the new version of FluentValidation:  https://github.com/Blazored/FluentValidation/tree/main/src/Blazored.FluentValidation I'll try to adapt my answer to the changes as soon as I can.

Answer (score 2):

So I've found something new here: [ASP.NET Core Blazor forms and validation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/forms-validation?view=aspnetcore-3.1#enable-the-submit-button-based-on-form-validation)

The `<ValidationSummary style="@displaySummary" />` is disabled by default and I enable it when there is an InvalidSubmit..

It's not an ideal solution because when a user *(1)* deletes the contents of a field then *(2)* clicks 'Submit' the validation will kick in but then if the users enters something valid in the same field *(3)* the user has to click 'Submit' twice. But for now I can live with this because this happens not so often.

The new working code:

```
@page "/cancel"
@using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

<h3>Cancel Validation</h3>

<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="OpenDialog">Open Dialog</button>
<hr />
<div>@((MarkupString)status)</div>

@if (showModal)
{
    <div class="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" style="display:block" id="taskModal">
        <div class="modal-dialog shadow-lg bg-white rounded" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title">Cancel Test</h5>
                    <button type="button" class="close" @onclick="CancelSubmit"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div>
                        <EditForm Model="@user" OnValidSubmit="HandleValidSubmit" OnInvalidSubmit="HandleInValidSubmit">
                            <DataAnnotationsValidator />
                            <ValidationSummary style="@displaySummary" />
                            <div class="form-group row">
                                <label class="col-3 col-form-label">Email</label>
                                <InputText class="col-8 form-control" @bind-Value="user.Email" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group row">
                                <label class="col-3 col-form-label">Password</label>
                                <InputText type="password" class="col-8 form-control" @bind-Value="user.Password" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-footer">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" @onclick="CancelSubmit">Cancel</button>
                            </div>
                        </EditForm>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

@code {

    public class UserLogin
    {
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Email is required")]
        public string Email { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Password is required")]
        public string Password { get; set; }
    }

    private UserLogin user = new UserLogin();

    bool showModal = false;
    private string displaySummary = "display:none";
    string status = "";

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        InitUser();
    }

    private void InitUser()
    {
        // for demo purposes, think of it as an 'edit dialog' in CRUD operation.
        status += "Init User";
        user.Email = "user@example.com";
        user.Password = "12345";
        displaySummary = "display:none";
    }

    private void OpenDialog()
    {
        status += "<br />Open User Dialog";
        showModal = true;
    }

    private void HandleValidSubmit()
    {
        status += "<br />Valid Submit";
        displaySummary = "display:none";
        showModal = false;
    }

    private void HandleInValidSubmit()
    {
        displaySummary = "display:block";
        status += "<br />Invalid Submit";
    }

    private void CancelSubmit()
    {
        status += "<br />Cancelled<br /><br />";
        InitUser(); // for demo purposes so you can test it multiple times
        showModal = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, @Jaap, your solution is problematic because it does not cope with the cause of this 'malfunctioning', but shift the issue from the Cancel button to the Submit button. I think that it's better the other way around. Your solution or a workaround, no matter how badly done, must at least, solve the problem outwardly without letting the user notice any malfunctioning. Anyhow, after learning and investigating the internals of the forms validation, I I've found a working solution, which performs as expected outwardly, at least... I'll post it later on with some explanation...

Comment: @enet It doesn't shift the problem from Cancel to Submit, that behavior stays the same. It was already there, but I didn't mention it previously. But yes, it's not an ideal solution. I agree, that's why I mentioned that in my answer. But I'm looking forward to see a better solution. I'm thinking about making this a Github issue, because it should work out of the box without any extra code I think.

Comment: shifting the problem from Cancel to Submit **outwardly**. In Github they'll redirect you back to stackoverflow. It can't work out of the box... Why. It's software, not magic.

Comment: You're right, I'd rather not use github for this. I've mentioned it on Twitter to some devs. And while you're right it isn't magic, since I started coding it feels like magic to me :)

Comment: "it feels like magic to me :) ", You mean you love it. I love it too...

Answer (score 1):

I put 2 handlers in my EditForm: one for OnValidSubmit (which should handle Cancel even if the form is valid), and another OnInvalidSubmit (to handle cancel when the form is invalid, so, some duplication but it works!). (Example shows using a Radzen card for the confirmation dialog, and my seemingly redundant Close and Confirm methods that I am still trying to figure out....).

```
<EditForm Model="@selectedUnit" OnValidSubmit="@Update" OnInvalidSubmit="@AreYouSure">
    <Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Forms.DataAnnotationsValidator />
    <Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Forms.ValidationSummary />
```

```
  <button type="submit" @onclick="@(() => selectedUnit.Action = "Save")" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
    <button @onclick="@(() => selectedUnit.Action = "Cancel")" class="btn btn-primary" >Cancel</button>
```

```
@code{
  public async void AreYouSure()
    {
// should use if to determine if they clicked Save or Cancel... this is the code for if Cancel //

        await dialogService.OpenAsync("Are you sure?", ds =>@<RadzenCard Style="padding: 20px;">
        <p Style="margin-bottom: 10px;">Changes will not be saved!</p>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <RadzenButton Text="Confirm Cancel Changes" Click="() => Confirm(true)" Style="margin-bottom: 10px; width: auto" />
                <RadzenButton Text="Oops! Continue Input" Click="() => ds.Close(false)" ButtonStyle="ButtonStyle.Secondary" Style="margin-bottom: 10px; width: auto" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </RadzenCard>);
        return;
    }

    private async Task Update()
    {
        if (selectedAppl.Action == "Cancel")
        {
            await dialogService.OpenAsync("Are you sure?", ds =>@<RadzenCard Style="padding: 20px;">
    <p Style="margin-bottom: 10px;">Changes will not be saved!</p>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <RadzenButton Text="Confirm Cancel Changes" Click="()=> Confirm(true)" Style="margin-bottom: 10px; width: auto" />
            <RadzenButton Text="Oops! Continue Input" Click="()=> ds.Close(false)" ButtonStyle="ButtonStyle.Secondary" Style="margin-bottom: 10px; width: auto" />
        </div>
    </div>
</RadzenCard>);
return;
};

   public void Confirm(bool confirmed)
    {
        if (confirmed)
        { ReturnToList(); }
        else
        {
            return;
        }
    }


    void Close(bool confirmed)
    {
        if (confirmed)
        { ReturnToList(); }
     
    }

  public void ReturnToList()
    {

        NavigationManager.NavigateTo("/Data/Counter");

    }
```